# dig returns different MX record, can anyone explain why?

Tags: dns

I have a domain lets call it `example.com` when I do: `dig example.com MX +short`, it returns:

```
10 mx1.[Internet_Service_Provider_Domain]
```

so, I decided to trace the DNS to check if there any possible **DNS Hijacking** attack, using the following command: `dig example.com MX +trace +short`, the result:

```
NS d.root-servers.net. from server 127.0.0.53 in 0 ms.
NS c.root-servers.net. from server 127.0.0.53 in 0 ms.
NS b.root-servers.net. from server 127.0.0.53 in 0 ms.
NS m.root-servers.net. from server 127.0.0.53 in 0 ms.
NS l.root-servers.net. from server 127.0.0.53 in 0 ms.
NS k.root-servers.net. from server 127.0.0.53 in 0 ms.
NS j.root-servers.net. from server 127.0.0.53 in 0 ms.
NS i.root-servers.net. from server 127.0.0.53 in 0 ms.
NS a.root-servers.net. from server 127.0.0.53 in 0 ms.
NS h.root-servers.net. from server 127.0.0.53 in 0 ms.
NS g.root-servers.net. from server 127.0.0.53 in 0 ms.
NS f.root-servers.net. from server 127.0.0.53 in 0 ms.
NS e.root-servers.net. from server 127.0.0.53 in 0 ms.
MX 10 [REAL_MAIL_MX_DOMAIN] from server [REAL_MAIL_MX_IP] in [TIME] ms.
```

but! in the second case `dig` returns the real information, while in the first returns ISP information.

can anyone explain why? plus, does something like this we can call it `DNS Hijacking`?

**[UPDATE-1]:**
when I use another DNS server, `8.8.8.8` for example, it returns the following:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 example.com MX +short
10 [REAL_MAIL_MX_DOMAIN]

$ dig @8.8.8.8 example.com MX +trace +short
NS a.root-servers.net. from server 8.8.8.8 in [TIME] ms.
NS b.root-servers.net. from server 8.8.8.8 in [TIME] ms.
NS c.root-servers.net. from server 8.8.8.8 in [TIME] ms.
NS d.root-servers.net. from server 8.8.8.8 in [TIME] ms.
NS e.root-servers.net. from server 8.8.8.8 in [TIME] ms.
NS f.root-servers.net. from server 8.8.8.8 in [TIME] ms.
NS g.root-servers.net. from server 8.8.8.8 in [TIME] ms.
NS h.root-servers.net. from server 8.8.8.8 in [TIME] ms.
NS i.root-servers.net. from server 8.8.8.8 in [TIME] ms.
NS j.root-servers.net. from server 8.8.8.8 in [TIME] ms.
NS k.root-servers.net. from server 8.8.8.8 in [TIME] ms.
NS l.root-servers.net. from server 8.8.8.8 in [TIME] ms.
NS m.root-servers.net. from server 8.8.8.8 in [TIME] ms.
RRSIG NS [DNSSEC_INFO] from server 8.8.8.8 in [TIME] ms.
MX 10 [REAL_MAIL_MX_DOMAIN] from server [REAL_MAIL_MX_IP] in [TIME] ms.
```

both with/without `+trace` returns the real information. I think there is somehow **DNS Hijacking**, am I right?

**[UPDATE-2]:** see [this comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/236466/dig-returns-different-mx-record-can-anyone-explain-why/236470#comment483672_236470).

Comment: "can anyone explain why?" Why not giving the real name to be able to really answer your question that does not seem clear at all... ?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I will explain it again in short: when I use `dig gmail.com MX +short`  the result: `10 mx1.[Internet_Service_Provider_Domain]`, but with `dig gmail.com MX +trace +short` the final result: `MX 30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. from server [...] in [..]  ms.`, **without** `+trace` `dig` returns ISP domain. **with** `+trace` returns `alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com` .. the question: *why*?

Comment: Without `+trace`, `dig` queries just the default recursive nameserver set up on your system, which is free to answer anything it wants. With `+trace`, `dig` does iterative queries starting from root and hence asks only authoritative nameservers and never your configured recursive ones. Hence it gets in theory "less" hijacked values (but this is mostly moot as DNS answers can also be modified in transit, except for domains having DNSSEC configured, which is NOT the case of `gmail.com`)

Comment: @patrick Thank you! It's clear now. Can you write it in an answer to make it the accepted one?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem before.  In my case the domain in question belonged to a client (let's call him 'Joe'), and the client had his own domain name (let's call it 'joescompany.com'), and the client had an email address at the domain (let's call it 'joe@joescompany.com').  Joe also had ISP service with a local ISP (let's call them joesisp.com).

Joe conveniently used joesisp.com's DNS server to host the DNS for joescompany.com.  He also used joesisp.com's mail server to host email for joescompany.com.  It just so happened that I also used joesisp.com for my ISP service as well.

Then, one day, Joe decided to move his joescompany.com domain away from joesisp.com.  He contracted with another provider to host the DNS for joescompany.com, and he used that company to host his email as well.  But, Joe didn't tell joesisp.com that he did this.  So, as far as joesisp.com was concerned, they thought they were still hosting the DNS for joescompany.com, and hosting mail for joescompany.com as well.

This didn't impact most people that sent Joe mail.  Mail sent to Joe by most senders arrived at Joe's new provider's mail server just fine.  But, when I would send mail to Joe it would get delivered to Joe's old mail server at joesisp.com.  That's because I was using joesisp.com as my ISP, and therefore I was using joesisp.com DNS servers, which (incorrectly) pointed the MX record for joescompany.com to their own MX servers.  All other DNS servers correctly pointed the MX records for joescompany.com to Joe's new MX servers, but joesisp.com's DNS servers still pointed to Joe's old MX servers.

Comment: But, in my case I'm the owner of that domain and server (VPS in another country), and l'm sure that company use another ISP. in addition, this problem appears on every `dig site MX` I do in my local device, once I use VPN or another DNS server it’s gone. So.. I think the ISP behind that, and they could hide that with `+trace` option.. I don’t want to be more paranoid.....

Comment: In that case, you might want to contact the provider whose DNS is returning the incorrect result, and ask them to investigate.

Comment: Which provider do you mean?

Comment: I mean the provider that is giving you the incorrect MX record.  Do a whois on the domain name to get the authoritative DNS server for your domain.  Then, query that DNS server for the MX records.  Then, you can use that to show the provider that is resolving the incorrect MX record that their DNS server is resolving incorrectly, and ask them to fix it.

Comment: And that's one reason why the same servers shouldn't be used for both authoritative and recursive roles.

Comment: thank you @mti2935 , the provider is my Internet Service Provider(which is a national telecom company), and I think they do some `DNS Hijacking` to read emails come/go through the country,  and they don't see it as "problem" or "bug" to fix it. @esa-jokinen can you explain more?

Comment: Name servers can be divided to authoritative name server hierarchy and recursive name servers that resolve names for the clients using this hierarchy. Mixing both recursive and authoritative functions on the same server has problems like reflector attacks ([RFC 5358](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5358)) and that a recursive server having authoritative zones could believe it's authoritative for a domain for which it isn't. Therefore, [IANA](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements) doesn't allow open recursive name service.

Comment: There's also a historical reason from an insecure implementation: BIND8 and BIND4, when memory is running out, could accidentally mix cached records with the authoritative zones, enabling DNS cache poisoning of the authoritative servers. In BIND9 there are protections against this, as those functionalities have been isolated to separate processes not sharing the same memory anymore.

Comment: Thank you @EsaJokinen , i will read more about this topic.